# How to sniff packets in GWT?

Tags: gwt, sniffing

I'm looking for a way to sniff packets in GWT or is there any other way to perform this task. I want to show a tree map of the incoming packets based on their size . One way which I thought is to use a cmd line packet sniffing tool which would output the details to a file, which could be read from GWT and then use that to display treemap.

Comment: GWT is client side, java is on the server and i'm sure java can sniff packets

Comment: It may be possible by using `((ServiceDefTarget) myServiceAsync).setRpcRequestBuilder(...)` but it's going to be difficult, because most of the code you'd need to change is either in private methods and/or doesn't follow Dependency Injection principles (I hope this will improve soon in GWT). Therefore, probably you'll have to copy/paste several methods in RequestBuilder, and finally hook into `com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(RequestCallback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and switching back to this project, One of the simplest way to do is with the help of a tool which could generate the the text file, which could be imported in the GWT code. For e.g. tcpdump could be used on Linux and once you have the output redirect it to a file, read that file in the code and then use that information in GWT code